# Entering values at specific locations in an array in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list `T2` and an array `X` containing numpy arrays of different shape. I want to rearrange values in these arrays according to `T2`. For example, for `X[0]`, the elements should occupy locations according to `T2[0]` and `0.` should be placed for locations not mentioned. Similarly, for `X[1]`, the elements should occupy locations according to `T2[1]`. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

T2 = [[0, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

X=np.array([np.array([4.23056174e+02, 3.39165087e+02, 3.98049092e+02, 3.68757486e+02]),
       np.array([4.23056174e+02, 3.48895801e+02, 3.48895801e+02, 3.92892424e+02])])
```

The expected output is

```
X=array([array([4.23056174e+02, 0, 0, 3.39165087e+02, 3.98049092e+02, 3.68757486e+02]),
      array([0, 4.23056174e+02, 3.48895801e+02, 3.48895801e+02, 3.92892424e+02])])
```

Comment: Do you need a jagged array as output?

Comment: Yes I would like to have the output as jagged array.

Comment: Then I would suggest looping over `zip(T2, X)` and doing each reindex separately

Comment: I have been trying for sometime now but no success :(

Comment: It may be simpler if `X` was a list of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

T2 = ...
X = ...

out = []

for t, x in zip(T2, X):
    temp = np.zeros(max(t) + 1)
    temp[t] = x
    out.append(temp)

out = np.array(out, dtype=object)
```

out:

```
array([array([423.056174,   0.      ,   0.      , 339.165087, 398.049092,
              368.757486])                                               ,
       array([  0.      , 423.056174, 348.895801, 348.895801, 392.892424])],
      dtype=object)
```